# Laravel 5.1 Sentinel::getUser() return null

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I am using Sentinel to authenticate users and as the auth Middleware.

Middleware code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    var_dump(Sentinel::guest()); // prints false
    if (Sentinel::guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Controller code:

```
public function getAccount() {
    var_dump(Sentinel::guest()); // prints true
    return Sentinel::getUser();
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('api/v1/temp/users/account', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@getAccount');
}
```

Then if i browse to `api/v1/temp/users/account` the var_dump() in the Middleware is printing false, while the var_dump() inside the controller is printing true which seems a nonsense.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out i was using the native facade instead of the Laravel facade `Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel`. That fixed.